# When to prefer the -ing ending over "which" / "who" / "to" / "that" etc. and vice versa?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, gerund-vs-infinitive

It seems to me that in many English sentences the **-ing** ending can replace words like **which** / **that** / **who** / **to** etc. Some examples:

> "I prefer **to study** in the library." **OR** "I prefer **studying** in the library."
>
> "I saw the car again **which hit** me when I crossed the street. **OR** "I saw the car again **hitting** me when I crossed the street.
>
> "I thing the man **who is wearing** the hat is wanted." **OR** "I thing the man **wearing** the hat is wanted."

When to prefer the *-ing* ending and when not? Are there rules? Does it depend on the tense or is either more common in certain regions or the target audience (official/colloquial)?
I am looking for general laws rather than for the best choise to those stupid example sentences.

(Feel free to edit, especially the tags)

**Whether duplicate or not:**

The linked question is just about the *to* and the *-ing* ending. I am not sure if this applies also do *which*, *who*, *that* etc. Also the linked question and answered doesn't say anything about regions and target audiences.

Comment: 'Which ..." is an adverbial phrase.  Without the 'which', 'hit[ting]' is part of a serial verb phrase (controlled by 'saw').  Also, 'hit' is past while 'hitting' is progressive.  In the serial verb phrase, the adverb[ial] 'again' is ambiguous where it is -- does it apply to the 'seeing' or the 'hitting'?